# Regex to extract number from a string with numbers

Tags: regex, ruby

I want a regex to extract the first number from a string with at least one number (assuming . is for decimal, and , is for separating thousands)

```
examples  = ["I earned $100,000", "I earned $100000", "I earned $100000.05"]
desired_output =  ["100000", "100000", "100000.05"]
```

Here is a regex I attempted:

```
regex = /((\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)(?:\.(\d{0,2}))?)/
```

However, for the string "I earned $100000", it extracts "100", NOT "100000".

```
regex.match("I earned $100000") #returns 100
```

How do I modify this regex?

Comment: Keep in mind that in Europe, the number 1,000,000.5 would be written 1.000.000,5 since the thousands separator is a period and the decimal point is a comma.

Comment: Is that the case also for the UK?

Comment: @Henley no, it's not

Comment: try out this https://regex101.com/r/81DpzM/1

Comment: I think the way to do this is in multiple steps, unless perhaps you want to use a function to remove all non-important characters

Comment: @Mark, that regex matches, for example, the string `'0000,0,0,....'`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland bold of you to assume that OP doesn't want it to match that :P

Comment: Using regular expressions for both extractions and validations in the same step is certainly possible, but it makes things more difficult to get right, and makes unit-testing of each step a lot harder. I'd avoid trying to do it this way as a matter of principle because it's harder to decompose and test interim results when you use a single, complex regular expression instead of multiple explicit transformation  and validation steps.

Answer (score 0):

You should first match the whole text `["100,000","100000","100000.5"]` and then remove unwanted separators.
the pattern: `[\d\,\.]+`

Your regex pattern only match 100 because you leave the 000 in uncaptured group

Answer (score 0):

```
examples = ["I earned $100,000", "I earned $100000", "I earned $100000.05"]
```

Code

```
p examples.map { |string| /\$([\d,.]+)/.match(string)[1] }
```

Output

```
["100,000", "100000", "100000.05"]
```

Comment: Perhaps `{ |string| string[/\$([\d,.]+)/] }`. Both match, however, `',,,,,,,'`, which probably is not wanted.

Comment: Should be `100000`, not `100,000`

Answer (score 0):

You could append word boundaries to prevent partial word matches, match 1+ digits instead and if you don't need the capture groups you can omit them:

```
\b\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{0,2})?\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OUo9rZ/1)

Comment: You may wish to ensure the first digit is not a zero, assuming, for example, `'007'` is not to be matched.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Hi there, all is well? I think you could use a capture group for that case `\b0*(\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{0,2})?)\b` https://regex101.com/r/2gr4wP/1

Comment: #4, I was thinking more along the lines of  `\b[1-9](?:\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*|\d*)(?:\.\d{2})?\b`.  I am pleased to report that all is well here, though last Saturday was a depressing day as I rolled a zero and became an octogenarian. Looking back, my second birthday was especially memorable because everybody was out celebrating it. There were even parades.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Good to hear you are still young at heart, rocking some Ruby and Regex. I'm hitting my mid fourties this month. No parties, but I am a sucker for the cake though :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm not sure it matters for the OP's example, but `$007.12` might be perfectly valid for a variety of use cases. Zero-padding and decimal precision greater than `2` are things you'll often see in accounting, for example. That's why I'd prefer to start the match on a non-captured currency symbol rather than a digit in the OP's case, because you're right: `007` by itself is extremely ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

### Extract Dollar Values, Then Validate & Transform

Assuming you're always using dollars and not some other currency, the following will work even if you have an empty String or more than one set currency values.

```rb
examples = [
  "I earned $100,000", "I earned $100000",
  "I earned $100000.05", "", 
  "I earned $2.50, which is half of $5.00"
]

examples.map { _1.scan(/\$(\d[\d,.]+)\b/).first }
  .compact.flatten.map { _1.delete ?, }

#=> ["100000", "100000", "100000.05", "2.50"]
```

This works by extracting all values with a leading dollar symbol, and then manipulating the matches. The steps include:

1. Using [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/String.html#method-i-scan) to capture all numbers (including decimals and commas) prefixed by a dollar sign and followed by a word boundary.

   - No effort is being made to validate edge cases in the set of examples such as explicit `nil` values, improperly-formatted values like `$1.00.2`, or negative values like `-$1.00` or `($5.00)`.
   - Also, note that leading or trailing zeroes are not necessarily errors; `$00.00` could be perfectly valid for some use cases, so leading zeroes, padding, decimal precision, or other things outside the scope of your question aren't addressed. You could do many of these validations with a more complex regexp, but I personally believe that you should validate your results *post facto* rather than try do it all within a single regexp to keep the cognitive load down. YMMV.
2. Select only the first dollar amount within the String if more than one is found.
3. Remove any `nil` values from the results.
4. Flatten the compacted Array of results.
5. Remove commas from the flattened Array of String values.

There are certainly shorter solutions, and solutions that will be more explicit about what is or isn't a valid dollar amount, but scanning for `/\$(\d[\d,.]+)\b/` just seems conceptually simpler to me. This allows you to move concerns about formatting and validations out of the core regexp.

Whether you deal with the result set using chained methods or by calling a sequence of "clean-up steps" on the results is up to you. IMHO, the less work you do inside the regular expression the easier it will be to debug any subsequent transformations or validations that are important to you.